# Conditional data conversion over a pandas column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with a string. The string will either have numbers or dates. So I need to convert that string into the proper format after assessing the type of data it contains.

This code doesn't work:

```
    temp_df['new_column']=pd.np.where(pd.to_numeric(temp_df['date_or_number'], errors='coerce').notnull().all()
                                            ,pd.to_numeric(temp_df['date_or_number'])
                                            ,pd.to_datetime(temp_df['date_or_number']))
```

---

TypeError: invalid type promotion

I get the error above. What method would you use to achieve this?
EDIT: To clarify, the column won't have numbers or dates at the same time, it will always have strings containing only numbers, or strings containing only dates. NEVER dates and numbers.

Comment: In a pandas dataframe, each column can only have one type, you can't have a different type for each row.

Comment: As gionni said you can't have different types for a single column

Comment: right, that aint happening here... this is a new column and the column being evaluated will only have either INTs or Dates, It won't have a mix of data types